# JFace - hiding ApplicationWindow menubar and toolbar?

Tags: swt, jface

I'm trying to make a method to hide the toolbar and menu in a JFace ApplicationWindow. I tried:

```
getToolBarControl().setVisible(false);
getMenuBarManager().setVisible(false);
```

This has no effect on the menu bar. It hides the ToolBar but still leaves the space where the ToolBar was.

(I'm trying to full-screen a composite by hiding them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overriding `ApplicationWindow.addMenuBar()` and `ApplicationWindow.addToolBar(int)` with empty methods.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I didn't understand, that you want to hide the controls only temporarily.

That's more complicated. `ApplicationWindow` overrides `Window.getLayout()`, and instantiates an `ApplicationWindowLayout` in this method. That layout does not provide an option to exclude a child temporarily.

You could override this method again and provide a `GridLayout` instance instead. To position you all direct children of your window, such as the toolbar, the menu, the status bar and your main content component, you need to set `GridData` instances on them. But if you do so, you can toggle `gridData.exclude` and call `window.layout()`, to show or hide the menu and tool bar.

Comment: It's not that I don't want them there at all, it's that I want to be able to show and hide them.